# How to manage order of entities? How to add Entity after or before one with some ID?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Let's assume I have to-do list app. You can add some tasks, mark them as "done" or move it up or down.

ToDoList:

- Task1
- Task2
- Task3
- Task4

Now I want to add some new task, let's say right after Task1 (so it will be on the second place).

When I simply _context.Tasks.Add() a new one, it will be saved as the last one, because EF won't know it should be second.

Of course I have some functions like ".OrderBy()", but what should be the value that I should use for ordering? How can I tell entity framework, to put it as a second in database?

Example Model:

```
public class TaskList
{
   public TaskList()
   {
      Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
   }
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You should create an actual Order column to indicate the order of the task on the list. That way, you can change order of tasks and just update the value.

Comment: @jpgrassi I hoped that there is some better solution, but OK, if it's necessary...

Comment: Not sure of what better solution you were looking for. As I understood, your task column has an auto-increment Id, and when you insert a new one, it goes down the "list", but this is the correct behavior. To control the order of your tasks, I don't see any other logical way.

Comment: If you don't want to work with an order column like you suggested, you'll have to manually assign Id's instead of auto-increment